# trying to create a simple game in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
//Minimal

    function dibujarAsteroide(x, y){     
            var fondo = document.getElementById("fondo");     
            var ctx = fondo.getContext("2d");     
            var asteroide = document.getElementById("asteroide");     
            y = 0;     
            x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);    
            ctx.drawImage(asteroide, x, y);      
            
            }
            
            function moverAsteroide(){     
                setInterval(dibujarAsteroide, 500);    
                var datosAsteroide = document.getElementById("asteroide");    
                datosAsteroide.style.top = 700 + "px";   
            }   

//Verificable
    <body>
            <section>      
                <canvas id="fondo" width = "600" height = "600"></canvas>     
                  <div>   
                  <img src="img/nave.png" id="nave"/>   
                  <img src="img/asceroide.png" id="asteroide"/>   
                  </div>   
                
                
            </section>   
        </body>   
        
        <script>     
          
            fondo=document.getElementById("fondo");   
            fondo.onclick=moverNave;   
            
            
            
            function moverNave(evento)   
            {     
             var nave=document.getElementById("nave");    
               x=evento.clientX;   
               y=evento.clientY;    
               
               if (x>=700 || y>=500){   
                 alert("fuera del espacio");   
               }   
               else    
               {      
                   nave.style.left=x+"px";    
                   nave.style.top=y+"px";    
               }    
               
            }   
            
            
            function dibujarAsteroide(x, y){    
                 var fondo = document.getElementById("fondo");
                 var ctx = fondo.getContext("2d");
                 var asteroide = document.getElementById("asteroide");
                 y = 0;
                 x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
                 ctx.drawImage(asteroide, x, y);
            
            }
            
            function moverAsteroide(){
                setInterval(dibujarAsteroide, 500);
                var datosAsteroide = document.getElementById("asteroide");
                datosAsteroide.style.top = 700 + "px";
            }
            
            
        </script>

/*Complete
This is the script*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
        <title>Nave</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <section>
            <canvas id="fondo" width = "600" height = "600"></canvas>
              <div>
              <img src="img/nave.png" id="nave"/>
              <img src="img/asceroide.png" id="asteroide"/>
              </div>
            
            
        </section>
    </body>
    
    <script>
      
        fondo=document.getElementById("fondo");
        fondo.onclick=moverNave;
        
        
        
        function moverNave(evento)
        {
         var nave=document.getElementById("nave");
           x=evento.clientX;
           y=evento.clientY;
           
           if (x>=700 || y>=500){
             alert("fuera del espacio");
           }
           else
           {
           nave.style.left=x+"px";
           nave.style.top=y+"px";
           }
           
        }
        
        
        function dibujarAsteroide(x, y){
        var fondo = document.getElementById("fondo");
        var ctx = fondo.getContext("2d");
        var asteroide = document.getElementById("asteroide");
        y = 0;
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
        ctx.drawImage(asteroide, x, y);
        
        }
        
        function moverAsteroide(){
            setInterval(dibujarAsteroide, 500);
            var datosAsteroide = document.getElementById("asteroide");
            datosAsteroide.style.top = 700 + "px";
        }
        
        
    </script>
        
    
</html>

//This the css code
#fondo
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url("../img/space.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}
#nave{
    position: absolute;
    left:375px;
    top: 300px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

#asteroide{
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition-duration: 5s;
    

}
```

The first function is supposed to draw the asteroid in a random location on top of the canvas.
The second one has to move it simulating a fall, I'm using transition property in my css to make the duration of the fall 3 seconds.

#### The problem

The asteroids didn't appeare randomly, it was only one and far out of the canvas. Is there anything wrong with the drawing function?

Comment: You have forgotten to ask the actual question though. What's your problem?

Comment: oh sorry I totally forgot about the main question. The asteroids didn't appeare randomly, it was only one and far out of the canvas. is there anything wrong with the drawing function?

Comment: And FYI - you can just indent code by 4 spaces instead of trying to wrap every line with back ticks and also you should edit the question to ask your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can test it out.

Comment: I tried to add everything that I used, please let me know if I'm missing something, I'm new and I'm trying to learn as fast as I can . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `setInterval('drawAsteroid', 500);` should be `setInterval(drawAsteroid, 500);` or `setInterval('drawAsteroid()', 500);`

Comment: Thank you, but it wasn't the problem, I updated with more code to improve the context.

Comment: I'm really sorry,  I tried both of your solutions but none worked, I have been trying everything but nothing seems to work and i'm starting to get really nervous.